# getting the html source of an open page in Google Chrome

Tags: html, vb.net, google-chrome

What ways can you have a VB.NET program get the html source of a document/page in an open Google Chrome browser?

Comment: What if there are multiple tabs open? Which one would you like to get the source for? And what if there are multiple Chrome windows and instances open?

Comment: You could write an extension which interacts with the NPAPI interface.

Comment: I want to get the source of all tabs and windows open. How does one go about writing an extension ComFreek can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Theveloper The extension will be very easy to write but I have no experience with the NPAPI interface yet. But it should definitely be possible!